# E1/3 function in python?

Tags: python, scipy, data-analysis, physics

I am analyzing some lab results with python and I need to fit the data to a distribution that includes the generalized exponential integral E<sub>1/3</sub>.
The closest thing I could find besides calculating the integral myself (which is very slow) is `scipy.special.expn(n, x)`, but it only supports integer values for n, and I need `n=1/3`.

Does anybody know if such a function exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

If writing your own using a quadrature routine isn't accurate enough you can consider using sympy. The function is implemented in [`sympy.functions.special.error_functions.expint`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.error_functions.expint). Since you want a numerical solution, you'll need to convert it to a float.

```py
import sympy as sp

def expn(n, x):
    return float(sp.functions.special.error_functions.expint(n, x))


print(expn(1/3,1))  # 0.3044294477841587
```

It's not fast, but it might do what you want.

Edit: Another alternative is to use the definition of the exponential integral based on the upper incomplete gamma function ([scipy has a normalized function for this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincc.html#scipy.special.gammaincc)), as per the [digital library of mathematical functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19#E2).

```py
from scipy.special import gammaincc, gamma

def expn(n, x):
    return x**(n-1)*gammaincc(1-n,x)*gamma(1-n)

print(expn(1/3, 1)) # 0.3044294477841586
```

---

### Old Solution

[Osama's solution](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19#E2) using quadrature isn't general enough, so I am including my own version below.

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

def expn(n, x):
    return quad(lambda t: np.exp(-x*t)/t**n, 1, np.inf)[0]

print(expn(1/3,1))  # 0.3044294477840883
```

In terms of accuracy, Mathematica reports the result to be 0.30442944778415870046. So, the above quadrature solution has a 2.312e-11% error. I can't imagine a higher accuracy solution would be necessary.

Comment: This is similar to what I've already done. It fails for small numbers at the scale of 1e-7 to 1e-6, which is the scale I need. I am currently running quads for the entire range from x=0 to x=1 with 1e-7 jumps, and I change the upper limit of the quad for smaller numbers so it's supposed to be more accurate. But again, this is not what i'm asking, i'm asking if the accurate numbers already exist somewhere so it would save me a lot of calculations

Comment: Those scales are for x or n?

Comment: Just edited the comment and saw your question. n is constantly 1/3

Comment: @bloop See my updated solution which includes a sympy and an alternative scipy solution.

Comment: Thank you, it's a better solution than what I had. I was hoping for a function that interpolates from an existing lookup table, and is fine enough for what I need, but I guess that it's too nieche... So i'll be using that to make my own lookup table

Comment: The third solution was very quick and is accurate enough, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define function for calculating this like

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(x):
    return np.exp(-x) / x**(1/3)

result, error = quad(integrand, 0, np.inf)
print(result)
```

But it applicable for academic usage where my instructor recommend a python library "mpmath" ref:[offical mpmath website](https://mpmath.org) which was much faster as compared to the function above. So modified snippet will be something like this:

```
import mpmath

def integrand(x):
    return mpmath.exp(-x) / x**(1/3)

result = mpmath.quad(integrand, [0, mpmath.inf])
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried using quad and the results are not accurate enough for what I need. I am asking if a premade function like expn exists that is not limited to integer n-s.